# Potential Bug with Automatically Populating Tabs

Tags: docusignapi

The api documentation says to Automatically Populate Tabs it says to prepend any tabLabel with '\\*'.

It says that the following will match any fields in the template "StudentLastName" to "Doe", and those with the tabLabel "StudentFirstName" to "John".

```
"tabs": {
  "textTabs": [
  {
    "tabLabel": "\\*StudentLastName",
    "value": "Doe"
  },
  {
    "tabLabel": "\\*StudentFirstName",
    "value": "John"
  }]
}
```

It's actually matching ***any label ending*** with "StudentLastName" to "Doe". So, if I have "Student1StudentLastName" and "Student2StudentLastName" they'll both match to "Doe".

Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

[API Link](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Automatically%20Populating%20Tabs.htm)

Comment: The API for what exactly...?

Comment: Docusign - per the tag. I added a link in the question as well.

Comment: Where did you find the "//*" reference in the DocuSign Documentation?

Comment: @RickeyS see the link in the original post

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm not sure why it's not working but I'm wondering if the stem (starting portion) of the `tabLabel` being the same is what's causing the issue.  As a test can you try using the following tabLabels:  `\\*LastNameStudent` and `\\*FirstNameStudent`?